# Compact Array of objects by value (Jquery or Underscore)

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, mapreduce, underscore.js

I have an array of objects:

```
"Entries" : [ {
        "FieldName" : "Name1",
        "FieldValue" : "N1Value1"
    }, {
        "FieldName" : "Name1",
        "FieldValue" : "N1Value2"
    }, {
        "FieldName" : "Name1",
        "FieldValue" : "N1Value3"
    }, {
        "FieldName" : "Name2",
        "FieldValue" : "N2Value1"
    }, {
        "FieldName" : "Name2",
        "FieldValue" : "N2Value2"
    }, {
        "FieldName" : "Name2",
        "FieldValue" : "N2Value3"
    }, {
        "FieldName" : "Name3",
        "FieldValue" : "N3Value1"
    }, {
        "FieldName" : "Name4",
        "FieldValue" : "N4Value1"
    }, {
        "FieldName" : "Name5",
        "FieldValue" : "N5Value1"
    } ]
```

I would like to transform it into:

```
"Entries" : [ {
          "FieldName" : "Name1",
          "FieldValue" : ["N1Value1","N1Value2","N1Value3"] 
      }, {
          "FieldName" : "Name2",
          "FieldValue" : ["N2Value1", "N2Value2", "N2Value3"]
      }, {
          "FieldName" : "Name3",
          "FieldValue" : "N3Value1"
      }, {
          "FieldName" : "Name4",
          "FieldValue" : "N4Value1"
      }, {
          "FieldName" : "Name5",
          "FieldValue" : "N5Value1"
      } ]
```

I have tried to first have unique FieldName values in an array, then to use _.filter in the JSON array in an attempt to receive an array in return, but all I get is the whole object.

```
    $.each(arrUniqueFieldNames, function() {
        var strFName = String(this);
        oEntries[this] = _.filter(jsonEntries, function (item) { 
            if (item.FieldName === strFName) {
                return String(item.FieldValue) 
            } 
        });
    });
```

There are maybe little imperfections in this code but it doesn't work as I was expecting as it returns the whole object and not only the value.

I tried also to replace _.filter with _.map, with the result however that I get for each an array with lots of "undefined".

Comment: If each array member has a unique `FieldName` property, is there a reason you want an array instead of a key/value store, like a `Map` or an `Object`? Your structure could be `Entries: {Name1: [...values...], Name2: [...values...]}` and so on. This gives you much faster lookup by name.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot modify the structure of the original JSON; otherwise, I'd have already gotten it how I wanted :( FieldName should be unique but it's not.

Comment: I'm not talking about the original data. I mean the transformation you want to do. You can transform it into the structure I described above instead of an array. If you don't actually need an array, then this would provide extremely fast lookup by name.

Comment: ...and FWIW, I'd make the `FieldValue` consistent so that it's always an Array, even if there's only one value in it.

Comment: Unfortunately, my role in this is just to fix the JSON in the format it was expected to be received, I have no power on how it's processed either!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know you want it with jquery but I'm not so firm with it so I give you a solution with pure JavaScript:

```
test =  [ {
    "FieldName" : "Name1",
    "FieldValue" : "N1Value1"
    }, {
    "FieldName" : "Name1",
    "FieldValue" : "N1Value2"
    }, {
    "FieldName" : "Name1",
    "FieldValue" : "N1Value3"
    }, {
    "FieldName" : "Name2",
    "FieldValue" : "N2Value1"
    }, {
    "FieldName" : "Name2",
    "FieldValue" : "N2Value2"
    }, {
    "FieldName" : "Name2",
    "FieldValue" : "N2Value3"
    }, {
    "FieldName" : "Name3",
    "FieldValue" : "N3Value1"
    }, {
    "FieldName" : "Name4",
    "FieldValue" : "N4Value1"
    }, {
    "FieldName" : "Name5",
    "FieldValue" : "N5Value1"
    } ];

result =[];

for (i=0; i<test.length; i++)
{
    element=test[i];
    key=element['FieldName'];
    value=element['FieldValue'];
    if (!(key in result))
        result[key] = [value];
    else
        result[key].push(value);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You have no idea how much relief your answer gave me! To think that I thought it was going to be simpler by using jquery or underscore! I am completely fine with a pure javascript solution! If anything, this is more readable and straightforward. I'm really thankful!

Comment: @Paprika ... though this approach at first glance makes a good impression, I do not consider it carefully crafted. It does not return a new array of field-items, grouped by equal names, as the OP was asking for. But it misuses the `result` array as (plain) object of non-numeric key-value pairs. Thus this array's length will always be Zero and therefore can not be iterated by any array iterator method.

Comment: @Peter Seliger   Your objection is right, but this is normal when you use associative arrays: they allways have a length of 0. If you want to iterate through it, you can do this with: for (key in result). This method is available since IE 9.

Comment: @Sascha ... At 1st, the OP wanted to have the final result to be mapped into an array. Thats what was ask for. At 2nd, if one provides a map/hash like structure, one already for reasons of readability should use a plain object instead of a list-like structure like an array. At 3rd, even with objects one might be better of, iterating their keys via `Object.keys` and then some additional array methods, instead of relying on a clumsy `for (key in result)`. Finally downvoting your critic's clean and working solution that exactly meets the OP's specification is of poor sportsmanship.

Comment: @Peter Seliger ... I didn't downvoting you. I suppose you downvoted me first to 0 and a few minutes later somebody else downvotes both of us at the same time. I never downvote somebody if there isn't any reason for it that means there is an error in it.

Comment: I'm down-voting this for all the reasons that @PeterSeliger gave, plus the fact that it creates many implicit global variables. This is definitely *not* a normal use of an array in JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

Another, maybe better reusable/maintainable solution, that also is purely language core based could use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and then might look like that ...

```js
var entries = [{
  "FieldName" : "Name1",
  "FieldValue": "N1Value1"
}, {
  "FieldName" : "Name1",
  "FieldValue": "N1Value2"
}, {
  "FieldName" : "Name1",
  "FieldValue": "N1Value3"
}, {
  "FieldName" : "Name2",
  "FieldValue": "N2Value1"
}, {
  "FieldName" : "Name2",
  "FieldValue": "N2Value2"
}, {
  "FieldName" : "Name2",
  "FieldValue": "N2Value3"
}, {
  "FieldName" : "Name3",
  "FieldValue": "N3Value1"
}, {
  "FieldName" : "Name4",
  "FieldValue": "N4Value1"
}, {
  "FieldName" : "Name5",
  "FieldValue": "N5Value1"
}];


function collectAndGroupValuesOfEquallyNamedFieldItems (collector, fieldItem) {
  var
    fieldName = fieldItem.FieldName,
    itemGroup = collector.map[fieldName];

  if (!itemGroup) {
    itemGroup  = collector.map[fieldName] = {

      "FieldName" : fieldName,
      "FieldValue": []
    };
    collector.list.push(itemGroup);
  }
  itemGroup.FieldValue.push(fieldItem.FieldValue);

  return collector;
}


entries = entries.reduce(collectAndGroupValuesOfEquallyNamedFieldItems, {

  map:  {},
  list: []

}).list;


console.log('entries : ', entries);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Addendum / Edit***

@Paprika ... taking into account @rockstar 's last comment, the above solution that recognizes the dual data structure of `FieldValue` too - `{String}` value for a single `FieldValue` value and `{Array<String>}` for multiple `FieldValue` values - does change to ...

```js
var entries = [{
  "FieldName" : "Name1",
  "FieldValue": "N1Value1"
}, {
  "FieldName" : "Name1",
  "FieldValue": "N1Value2"
}, {
  "FieldName" : "Name1",
  "FieldValue": "N1Value3"
}, {
  "FieldName" : "Name2",
  "FieldValue": "N2Value1"
}, {
  "FieldName" : "Name2",
  "FieldValue": "N2Value2"
}, {
  "FieldName" : "Name2",
  "FieldValue": "N2Value3"
}, {
  "FieldName" : "Name3",
  "FieldValue": "N3Value1"
}, {
  "FieldName" : "Name4",
  "FieldValue": "N4Value1"
}, {
  "FieldName" : "Name5",
  "FieldValue": "N5Value1"
}];


function collectAndGroupValuesOfEquallyNamedFieldItems (collector, fieldItem) {
  var
    fieldName = fieldItem.FieldName,
    itemGroup = collector.map[fieldName];

  if (!itemGroup) {
    itemGroup  = collector.map[fieldName] = {

      "FieldName" : fieldName,
      "FieldValue": null
    };
    collector.list.push(itemGroup);
  }
  if (Array.isArray(itemGroup.FieldValue)) { // list/array of multiple string values.

    itemGroup.FieldValue.push(fieldItem.FieldValue);

  } else if (typeof itemGroup.FieldValue === 'string') { // data structure switch.

    itemGroup.FieldValue = [itemGroup.FieldValue, fieldItem.FieldValue]

  } else if (itemGroup.FieldValue === null) { // initial string value.

    itemGroup.FieldValue = fieldItem.FieldValue;
  }
  return collector;
}


entries = entries.reduce(collectAndGroupValuesOfEquallyNamedFieldItems, {

  map:  {},
  list: []

}).list;


console.log('entries : ', entries);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'd just point out that the result that the OP provides has a string when the `FieldValue` has only one item, instead of an array with a single member. But then I have the feeling that the OP doesn't quite know what he wants.

Comment: There is an addendum that takes into account @rockstar 's last comment and slightly changes the implementation of the first given solution towards recognizing the dual nature of a `"FieldValue"`s data structure.